# Customize x axis range

Tags: r, histogram, axis

I want to change the x axis range of my histogram.
How can I remove all hours for which there is no data from the x axis?

[image]
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can artificially squeeze the values together is to change the bin size. Here is a randomly generated extreme bimodal distribution like yours. In each bar is 500 counts of data:

```
hist(rbinom(n=1000,
       size=1,
       prob = .50))
```

[image]

If we simply reduce the number of bins that the values go into, it reduces the gap in between the values and labeling below where they lie:

```
hist(rbinom(n=1000,
            size=1,
            prob = .50),
     breaks = 3)
```

[image]

The problem lies in that data won't be represented accurately depending on what you're doing, so I would suggest explaining *why* you made that decision if you share this elsewhere.

A less extreme example below with various counts but still gaps:

```
hist(rbinom(n=1000,
        size=10,
        prob = .20))
```

[image]
And here if we shift the bins again, they will distribute in the plot with less gaps, making it more right skewed but more distribution within the bars:

```
hist(rbinom(n=1000,
            size=10,
            prob = .20),
     breaks = 6)
```

[image]

As far as I'm aware there isn't really a way to just remove the values in between the plot. For one, its a distribution plot, so whatever values you remove a priori will just redistribute when you generate the plot. Second, if there is in fact a way, and I wouldn't doubt there is, your x axis would look strange, as you would have a bunch of missing data unaccounted for, looking like this:

[image]

Therefore, changing the bins, showing where the data is actually allocated, is probably the best choice.

Comment: No problem! Make sure to accept my answer with the checkmark please :)